# How to create code that searches for a word in a .txt file and counts the amount of times it occurs in C?

Tags: c, arrays, search

FYI I am fairly new to coding in C. I am looking for a way to search a .txt file for a certain word that is inputted by the user and counts the number of times it occurs within the .txt file. I currently have the .txt file in a 2D array. I have no idea how to even start. Please help!

Comment: no it wouldnt be

Comment: how would I count the number of times the word occurs in the .txt file if I used strcmp? Doesn't strcmp only give back a boolean value (so true or false)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I don't know where to start" is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the standard library function [`strstr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html). Read the description, and think about how you'd apply it to your 2D array (of, presumably, `char*`).